# Как поменять порядок существующих столбцов в PostgreSQL таблице?

Tags: postgresql

Есть очень простая таблица без входных данных которая была уже создана раньше:

```
CREATE TABLE test1_test (
first_name VARCHAR (50),
last_name VARCHAR (50),
birth_date DATE,
gender VARCHAR (50),
email VARCHAR (50));
```

Подскажите, как я могу поменять положение столбца `gender` отправив его например на первое место

В MySQL я знаю что это можно сделать при помощи команды:

```
ALTER TABLE myitems MODIFY COLUMN Quantity INT(20) AFTER UserID;
```

В PostgreSQL так сделать к сожалению нельзя. Подскажите как сделать правильно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/how-do-i-alter-the-position-of-a-column-in-a-postgresql-database-table#:~:text=%22Alter%20column%20position%22%20in%20the,you%20reach%20the%20desired%20layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если посмотреть на ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/how-do-i-alter-the-position-of-a-column-in-a-postgresql-database-table#:%7E:text=%22Alter%20column%20position%22%20in%20the,you%20reach%20the%20desired%20layout.) и

цитату [отсюда](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position)

> Many people new to postgresql often ask if it has support for altering
> column positions within a table. Currently it does not; if you want to
> change column positions, you must either recreate the table, or add
> new columns and move data.

По сути нельзя так как вам хотелось. Но есть способы решить проблему иначе. Пересоздать таблицу с колонками как вам нужно и перенести данные либо добавлять колонки и существующую таблицу и крутить до получения нужного порядка.

PS. А по хорошему нет в этом смысла. Если нужен порядок то вы всегда можете извлекать данные в нужном вам порядке.

Comment: Смысл есть, ибо [выравнивание влияет на размер](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6A9MCYvknRNBJcKHpFNZmU/0).  Но сделать нельзя.